# Timer not resuming after game loosing focus

Tags: java, timer, libgdx

I have a recurring task. I schedule it in the standard way (`Timer` is the `libgdx` one: `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer`):

```
Timer.schedule(myTask, 2, 2);
```

When the user wants to pause the game, I call:

```
Timer.instance().stop();
```

to pause the execution of the task. When the user resumes the game I call:

```
Timer.instance().start();
```

This works well, but if the user:

1. Pauses the game
2. Makes the game to loose focus (e.g, by focusing on a different window)
3. Resumes the game

   the task is never fired again. Any ideas how this can be solved?

### Update

I've opened this issue as a possible bug in `libgdx`: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3181

Comment: Are you overriding onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState()? You might need to reschedule your task on restore. Also does Timer.schedule happen in onCreate or onStart? If it was in onStart you'd think it would get rescheduled on restart.

Comment: @JimW Not overriding those methods at the moment. I'm trying to understand wether or not this is a `libgdx` issue or if I'm not using the `Timer` as I should.

Comment: You might do some reading on the Android lifecycle. Your app should be prepared to save it's internal state (if you have any) in case the device wants to page your app out and/or bring another app to focus.

Comment: @JimW this question is not specific to android. The issue I'm experiencing happens while running the game on my MacBook. That's why I doubt it has to do with Android's lifecycle.

Comment: @user2016436 You should write an answer of your own and mark as accepted for future readers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was indeed a bug in libgdx. It was [fixed](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/bcc1e9e3770665d886b13a3e8359c78507a81c9c) and now this issue is gone (I'm using `libgdx` 1.6.2-SNAPSHOT version).

Thanks go to the great team of libgdx!